# Return dynamic or union type from lambda in Java

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I'm returning to Java after having been away for a very, very long time, and I'm trying to do in Java the sort of thing that I've often done in Javascript or Typescript. But I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to create a mapping between two different systems to easily map types and copy values from one system to the other. The systems are Neo4j and Excel, although my question doesn't really have anything to do with either of those. Basically the idea is that users can export data from Neo4j to an Excel sheet, edit values there, and then import it again. (I know! It's a terrible idea! But they really want it and we can blame them if they mess up.)

Still, at the very least I'd like them to not change the types of data in neo4j properties, so I'm building a fairly strict mapping:

```
public enum Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping {
  STRING("String", cell -> cell.getStringCellValue()),
  INTEGER("Integer", cell -> cell.getNumericCellValue()),
  FLOAT("Float", cell -> cell.getNumericCellValue()),
  BOOLEAN("Boolean", cell -> cell.getBooleanCellValue()),
  STRING_ARRAY("String[]",
        cell -> Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping.deserializeArrayToString(cell.getStringCellValue()),
        value -> serializeArray((Object[]) value)
  ),
  DATE("Date",
        cell -> LocalDate.parse(cell.getStringCellValue()),
        value -> ((LocalDate)value).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)),
  );

  interface ExcelCellReader {
      Object readValue(Cell cell);
  }
  interface ExcelCellWriter {
      Object writeValue(Object value);
  }

  public final String className;
  public final ExcelCellReader excelCellReader;
  public final ExcelCellWriter excelCellWriter;

  private Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping(String className, ExcelCellReader excelCellReader) {
      this.className = className;
      this.excelCellReader = excelCellReader;
      this.excelCellWriter = value -> value;
  }

  private Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping(String className, ExcelCellReader excelCellReader, ExcelCellWriter excelCellWriter) {
      this.className = className;
      this.excelCellReader = excelCellReader;
      this.excelCellWriter = excelCellWriter;
  }

  public static Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping fromNeo4jType(String type) {
      for (Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping instance : Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping.values()) {
          if (instance.className.equals(type)) {
              return instance;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

(I'm leaving out the serialization/deserialization of arrays in a readable manner, because that's a whole separate issue.)

This code seems fine. The IDE doesn't complain about it at least. But then I try to use it in a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testStringMapping() {
    String testString = "Test String";
    VirtualNode node = new VirtualNode(1);
    node.setProperty("test", testString);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    String neo4jType = node.getProperty("test").getClass().getSimpleName();
    Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping mapping = Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping.fromNeo4jType(neo4jType);
    cell.setCellValue(mapping.excelCellWriter.writeValue(node.getProperty("test")));
}
```

Here, the problem is that `cell.setCellValue()` expects a specific type. It's heavily overloaded, so it can accept String, Integer, Float, various Dates, and more. But not Object. Now all the objects I'm returning from my lambda will be one of those types, but the lambda itself says it's returning an Object, and Java doesn't like that.

In TypeScript, I might have it return `String|Integer|Float|Date`, but you can't do that in Java. Is it possible to do this with generics somehow?

I don't want to explicitly cast in `cell.setCellValue((String)mapping.excelCellWriter.writeValue(node.getProperty("test")));` because this is just going to be a single line that should work for all data types. I wrote the enum exactly to handle this, but it can't seem to handle this one final cast. I suspect some generic type magic could do it, but I never really mastered that aspect of Java.

(Also: I'm not a fan of the `excelWriter.writeValue()`. Is there a way to make `excelWriter()` both a property of the enum and the function that's called? Or is that too JavaScript of me?)

Comment: Have a `#setCellValue(Cell, VirtualNode)` method within your `Neo4jExcelDataTypeMapping` class, which can write the data accordingly without having to guess the type. I would also avoid `public` fields, though you _may_ be safe in this instance if those fields are immutable (since they're also `final`), it still would require you to keep those public fields in the long-term.

Comment: I just wrote a workaround where I'm added the Cell as a parameter to the excelWriter() lambda. This works, but I'm not a fan. Passing both the Cell and the VirtualNode is a nice idea; it makes the operation more symmetrical in a way, except then I also need the property name to access the property from the node. A Node represents a whole Row.

I've also tried giving the enum a generic type argument, but that's not allowed in Java. Could I do this in a class?

Comment: There's no such concept as *Union type* in Java because it doesn't make sense without dynamic typing (Java is statically typed). For the same reason, using `Object` as a type doesn't give any advantage in Java, conversely it impairs the code by forcing you to use `instanceof` checks and casting (it's not a good practice in Java). You can't use the full power of a language by trying to reproduce your experience in another language. In Java we have a concept of [*generics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), try to use them in place of Object: `T writeValue(T t);`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I've been trying to use generics, but that doesn't seem to be allowed in either enums or lambdas. I'd love to give each enum instance the type it's meant to support, but either it's not allowed, or I'm doing it wrong.